# Style last div with class row

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I'm trying to style the last div with the class row on the page with a margin-bottom, but I can't seem to select it.

I have this:

```
body div.row:last-child { margin-bottom: 3em !important; }
```

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you post up your HTML as well?

Comment: Use body>div:last-of-type. See example: http://liveweave.com/muqgZh

Answer (score 3):

Here's your code:

http://liveweave.com/muqgZh

Use `body>div:last-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

-Edit-

`last-of-type` doesn't care about the `.row`. So, you could do this:

#### JS (jQuery)

```
$('div.row:last').addClass('last');
```

#### CSS

```
body>div.row.last {
   margin-bottom: 3em !important;
}
```

<strike>You're looking for `:last-of-type`</strike>

```
body>div.row:last-of-type {
   margin-bottom: 3em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've provided [should work](http://jsfiddle.net/Fgszh/) if your `div.row` is definitely the very last element in `body`.

If it's the last `div`, you can always try `:last-of-type` instead ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fgszh/1/)).

If it isn't the last `div` but you do know how many other elements come after it, you can use `:nth-last-child(n)` ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Fgszh/2/)).

Answer (score 0):

You can select in CSS:

- each `.row` that is the last child (or `:last-of-type`) of their parent,
- the last `.row` that is direct child of `body` (or direct child of the last child of body or any known and fixed level of hierarchy)

but you can't select the last `.row` appearing in the HTML code whatever its level of hierarchy